# Can you generalize the Triangle group to other polygons?

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

The [Triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group) is the group of reflections of by triangles in a tessellation by congruent triangles. If the angles of the triangles are $\frac \pi l$, $\frac \pi m$, and $\frac \pi n$, then the group is isomorphic too

$$\Delta(l,m,n) = \langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^l = (bc)^n = (ca)^m = 1 \rangle$$

There is of course a group like this corresponding to any tessellation, which will be a subgroup of the proper [Isometry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group).

My question is, how do we find a group presentation of a tessellation by congruent $k$-gons?

Comment: There are only a finite number of planar tesselations, and while there are infinitely many hyperbolic characterizations, they're all straightforwardly categorizable. I highly recommend the book _The Symmetries of Things_, which answers this question in depth, including explaining exactly how to read out the presentation of a group from its fundamental regions.

Comment: The wallpaper group covers all of the repeating patterns that the plane.  The triangle group is a subgroup of this group.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group

Answer (score 1):

Concretely, if $P$ is a convex polygon in a plane $X$ (a complete simply connected Riemannian surface of constant curvature, i.e. the Euclidean plane, the hyperbolic plane or a round sphere) with the consecutive angles $\frac{\pi}{n_1},..., \frac{\pi}{n_k}$, then the group $G$ of isometries of $X$ generated by isometric reflections in the edges of $P$ has the presentation
$$
\langle s_1,...,s_n| s_i^2, (s_i s_{i+1})^{n_i}, i=1,...,k\rangle.
$$